# Parameter to the Trait in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, traits

I need a trait with takes a parameter and uses it for creation of implicit object. In the following way.

```
trait SparkSessionTrait(name:String) {

  implicit val sparkSession = SparkSession
                                .builder()
                                .appName("AcoE Workflow_${name}")
                                .master("yarn")
                                .enableHiveSupport()
                                .getOrCreate()
}
```

**How can i pass the args(0) as a parameter to the SParkSessionTrait**

We can do if it is a case class but in my case it is an Object

```
object Test extends SparkSessionTrait{




  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val name = args(0)


    sparkSession.catalog.clearCache()
}
```

Comment: @JeffreyChung case class takes parameters and they are initalized in the trait. But Object doesnt take parameters

Comment: Create a Test class which takes a parameter and create a companion object then override apply method and create an object of the test class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you want to do it simply doesn't make sense.

```
trait SparkSessionTrait(name:String)
```

isn't allowed (but will be in Scala 3 with some limitations), it needs to be a `class`.

But the more important issue is that if you extend a class with parameters (or trait in Scala 3, that doesn't matter), these parameters need to be known at construction time. I.e. you must have `object Text extends SomeSessionTrait(someName)`. By the time `main` method is called, it's far too late, you can't set `name` from there.

One way to change the program and make it compile is

```
class SparkSessionTrait(name:String) {
  implicit val sparkSession = SparkSession
                                .builder()
                                .appName("AcoE Workflow_${name}")
                                .master("yarn")
                                .enableHiveSupport()
                                .getOrCreate()
}

object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val name = args(0)
    val sessionTrait = new SparkSessionTrait(name)
    import sessionTrait._

    sparkSession.catalog.clearCache()
}
```